# sidebar issues -despite position:fixed sidebar won't stay in it's place.. code & image included

Tags: css, position

This is my first attempt and designing/coding a site on my own, and I've learned a lot thus far and as I'm putting the final touches on I can't seem to correct this one last issue.
Ideally the sidebar should be in a fixed position on the far right, horizontally level with the nav on the left side. Currently, it sits on top of the main content near the header/nav on the left.

[image]

```
header {
    background: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 123px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 158px; 
}
#main {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-top: 310px;
}
#sidebar {
    border-top: 1px solid #202020;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 252px;
    margin-top: 295px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 158px;
}

    <header>
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="whskytngfxtrt logo" height="139" width="158" /></a>
        </div><!-- end logo -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li id="blog"><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                <li id="work"><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
                <li id="about"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav><!-- end nav -->
    </header><!-- end header -->

    <div id="main">
        <article>
            <h1><a href="#">Clever Headline</a></h1>
            <h2 class="postinfo">
            <ul>
                <li>Posted by <a href="#">Alex Chennault</a></li>
                <li>1st March 2012</li>
                <li>tags: <a href="#">cool</a>, <a href="#">awesome</a></li>
            </ul>
            </h2>
            <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me? " he thought. It wasn't a dream. His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls. A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer.</p>
        </article><!-- end article -->
    </div><!-- end main -->

    <div id="sidebar">
        <section id="dictionary">
            <h3><b>hwis-kee tang-goh foks-trot</b></h3>
            <h4><p><i>noun</i> 1. the best damn creative studio there ever was</p></h4>
        </section><!-- end dictionary -->

        <section id="twitter">
            <h3><a href="http://www.twitter.com/whskytngfxtrt">@whskytngfxtrt</a></h3>
            <h4><ul>
                <li><a href="#">sometimes i just really love the internet</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sometimes i just really love the internet</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sometimes i just really love the internet</a></li>
            </ul></h4>
        </section><!-- end twitter-feed -->
    </div><!-- end sidebar -->
```

Comment: Do you mean that your nav ul li will be aligned _horizontally_ under the logo and separating border line? If not, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things you may want to adjust:

1. You are adding some properties to your style rule that are pushing your content lower, namely:

   ```
   margin-top: 295px;
   padding-top: 25px;
   ```

   You might want to reduce or eliminate those.
2. You have the position set to `fixed` but you are not using any of the properties specific to it to set the position, e.g., `top`, `left`.  You can read a bit more here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/position

Comment: What do you mean by pushing my content lower? It is currently where I intend it to be on a vertical axis, I just need it pushed along the horizontal axis.

Also, could you elaborate on the position properties? I've experimented a bit with the things mentioned on sitepoint, but nothing seems to make a difference with the exception of setting the top and left values to 0.